# mysql query to select one column where "" return only one result

Tags: php, mysql

Here we go, my first question on stack overflow.

```
$conn->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

  $sql = "SELECT nodeurl FROM ownership where userid = 'jgm'";

$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(); 
        $config = $stmt->fetch();
$xx = sizeof($config);

echo var_dump($config);
```

mysql table is like this :

```
id - nodeurl - userid
-----------------------
1  - url_a   - jgm
2  - url_b   - jgm
3  - url_c   - seb
4  - url_d   - jgm
```

If I do the query : `"SELECT nodeurl FROM ownership where userid = 'jgm'"` I'm expecting the result to get in an array url_a, url_b and url_d

and if I do it for 'seb' i should get back url_c

I'm running the query via my mysql client console, it work just fine. when i'm executing the code via my php, I receive only the first result ( one row only ).

I'm completely stuck on that.

Comment: [`PDOStatement::fetch()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) only returns one of the results. You can use [`PDOStatement::fetchAll()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php) to get all the results.

Answer (score 1):

when your statement will return more than 1 row, you will have to use a function to retrive all the data in to an array. For me i like to use fetch_assoc

```
$conn->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

  $sql = "SELECT nodeurl FROM ownership where userid = 'jgm'";

$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$result = $stmt->execute(); 
while($config = $result->fetch_assoc()){
$xx = sizeof($config);

echo var_dump($config);
}
```

Comment: If my answer helped you, feel free to vote up and select as the accepted answer :)

Answer (score 1):

I have 2 tables in my db
one is "nodes"
other is "nodes config"

Nodes is like this :
[my tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jYuC6.jpg)

Actualy, this is my code

```
 $sql = "SELECT nodeurl FROM ownership where userid = 'jgm'";

$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(); 
echo "<select>";
while($config = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){    
    echo "<option value='".$config['nodeurl']."'>".$config['nodeurl']."</option>";
}
echo "</select>";

}
```

It does create a drop list of all the url that are owned by 'jgm' ( i'll replace that by a variable of course ). Its ok for each option value to be the url itself, but i'd like the label of each option to be the Name from the tables "node name" that is corresponding with the url because they will be much more easier for the user to select.